# Getting the checkbox values using variable and loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many checkboxes and I want to get the checked ones with a loop and not by using if statements for each one. The code (it doesn't work) is the following:

```
 (1..66).each do |i|
    $st = "a"+i.to_s
    if params[:$st]
      @cat = Categories.new
      @cat.af_id = @af.id
      @cat.cat_id = i
      @cat.save
     end
  end
```

The checkboxes are named a1-a66. I guess that it constructs something like params[:"a1"], I mean that it adds quotes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how that will work in a clean way.

Needs some refactoring.

Try to extract your parameters to an array

```
def get_cat_ids(params)
  @cat_ids = params.dup.keep_if { |k,v| k.to_s[/^a\d+/].present? }.values
end
#@cat_ids = [1, 2, 4, 32, 65]
```

so that you will be able to do a simple

```
@cat_ids.each do |cat_id|
  cat = Categories.new
  cat.af_id = @af.id
  cat.cat_id = cat_id
  cat.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..66).each do |i|
    $st = "a"+i.to_s
    if params[$st.parameterize.to_sym]
      @cat = Categories.new
      @cat.af_id = @af.id
      @cat.cat_id = i
      @cat.save
     end
  end
```

parameterize.to_sym solved my problem..